# Theoretical inquiry about listviews and multiple activities in android studio

Tags: android, listview

New developer here, for a personal project I want to develop a shop like app. I was wondering if it's possible to have one listview, and upon clicking each entry bring up another listview for each entry, and then upon clicking that it will bring up a page for each product.

Do I need separate activities for each product and listview I want to make? Or is it possible to make a few listviews and have the listview grab the string[]?

Comment: You may want ExpandableListView.  Or you may just need to launch a 2nd activity or page in a fragment when you choose something in the first list view.  Depends on the style you want.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, it is possible to have several `ListViews` and one activity. However, you should think about if the UX you want to achieve will be **intuitive and familiar for your users**, and preferably following [Material Design guidelines](https://material.io/guidelines/). For example, take a look at the approach Google Play Store app took with with tabs, chips, and lists / grids.